# Stuck in "Waiting for the operation to be included..." Infinitely

Tags: operation

**What is the cause and how to fix?**

Stuck in `Waiting for the operation to be included...` Infinitely.

Comment: Could you specify the wallet you are using ? To which node the wallet is connected ?

Comment: I'm using the default tezos-client wallet and a alphanet node. The problem was that my internet is really slow and will take some days for the node to sync.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that your node is not fully synchronized yet or the fee you specified/defaulted is too low for any baker to include the operation.

**Verifying if node is Synchronized:**

```
./tezos-client get timestamp && date -u -Isec
  or
./alphanet.sh client get timestamp && date -u -Isec ( For Docker Users )
```

Those commands will return two UTC timestamps, the current timestamp of the head of the chain and current time.

For the node to be synched those timestamps need to match, if they don't just wait and keep checking the timestamps.

If the head timestamp isn't moving, try restarting the node.

**How to solve:**

- Wait for the node to finish synchronizing;
- Increase the Fee you are giving to the operation;

*Credits: @fredcy and @braveheart*

Answer (score 3):

In case your node isn't fully bootstrapped, you can run:

```
tezos-client bootstrapped
```

This command will let you know in case your node isn't fully synced.

Comment: `tezos-client bootstrapped` output can be misleading, in some occasions can tell that the node is fully bootstrapped when it really isn't.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug for the tezos project at Gitlab?

Comment: A possible bug or something missing in documentation.

Comment: There is already a branch with better bootstrapped heuristics